# How to prove debian 9 installed with encryption enforcement on all partitions?

Tags: debian, encryption

When I installed Debian 9 I chose the option to encrypt the partitions.

I'm guessing of course they are encrypted when I log out. But I need to be able to demonstrate to a client that they are encrypted since it is the clients security policy.

I have read some posts but none answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer with a live USB flash disk and mount the partitions. If you succeed in mounting the partitions without supplying a password, they are not encrypted.

Alternative, affirmative proof: start the Disks utility either in the installed OS or a live OS and see if it shows the partitions as encrypted.